# __callStatic does not call if there exist a non-static function

Tags: php

my code like that:

```
<?php

class A {

    public function CallA()
    {
        echo "callA" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function CallB()
    {
        echo "callB" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        echo "callStatic {$method}";
    }
}

A::CallA();
```

but It will echo :

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method A::CallA() should not be called statically in /vagrant/hades_install/public/test.php on line 21
callA
```

that is say, `CallA` does not run into function `__callStatic`

how can i do if i want the `__callStatic` be called by use `A::CallA()`

Comment: If you *can* change the public access to protected or private for `CallA` then you will see `__callStatic()` fire before `CallA` as expected, but that means that `CallA` cannot be called without `__callStatic()`... the conundrum!

Comment: The `static` keyword for methods in PHP is more or less advisory only. It doesn't greatly influence the call behaviour at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) explains:

> [`__callStatic()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

The method `CallA()` in your code **is** accessible, this is why PHP does not use `__callStatic()` and calling `CallA()` directly is its only option.

You can force the invocation of `__callStatic()` either by making `CallA()` inaccessible (rename it or change its visibility to `protected` or `private`) or by calling it directly (ugly workaround):

```
A::__callStatic('CallA', array());
```

If you choose to make `CallA()` protected you need to implement the method [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) to be able to call `CallA()` again:

```
class A {

    protected function CallA()
    {
        echo "callA" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function CallB()
    {
        echo "callB" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        echo "callStatic {$method}" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if ($method == 'CallA') {
            $this->CallA();
        }
    }
}

A::CallA();
A::__callStatic('CallA', array());

$x = new A();
$x->CallA();
```

It outputs:

```
callStatic CallA
callStatic CallA
callA
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to keep the non-static method intact and use a prefix when calling it statically, resolving the method name within `__callStatic`.

```
class A {

    public function CallA()
    {
        echo "callA" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $method_name = ltrim($method, '_');
        echo "callStatic {$method_name}" . PHP_EOL;

        $instance = new A();
        return instance->$method_name(...$args); //this only works in PHP 5.6+, for earlier versions use call_user_func_array
    }

}

A::_CallA();
```

This will output:

```
callStatic callA
callA
```